# How to get around vuetify's v-select internal state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to prevent a value from being 'selected' when using vuetify's v-select component.

Given:

```
<v-checkbox
    v-model="allowChanges"
></v-checkbox>
<v-select
    v-model="twoWayComputed"
    :items="items"
></v-select>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    selected: "Foo",
    allowChanges: false,
    items: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Fizz', 'Buzz']
  }),
  computed: {
    twoWayComputed: {
      get(){
        return this.selected
      },
      set(val){
        if (this.allowChanges){
          console.log("updating")
          this.selected = val
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYNVKN?editors=1011

When another value is selected, the components selected value is not being updated. However v-select still shows the new selected value.

I even tried all kinds of "tricks" like

```
  set(val){
    if (this.allowChanges){
      console.log("updating")
      this.selected = val
    } else {
      this.selected = this.selected
    }
```

but no luck.

I believe v-select is maintaining its own internal selected value.

Comment: Could you just add `:disabled="!allowChanges"` to the `v-select`?   Like this: `<v-select
                    v-model="twoWayComputed"
            :items="items"
            label="Standard"
            :disabled="!allowChanges"
          ></v-select>`

Comment: You could but that's not the UX that was dictated. For reference the desire is to pop a modal if a change is made and there are unsaved changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does nothing:

> this.selected = this.selected

You have to set the value, wait for vue to update the props, then set it back again:

```
const oldVal = this.selected
this.selected = val
this.$nextTick(() => {
  this.selected = oldVal
})
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WqeRXa?editors=1011)

Comment: I tried something similar to this but was unsuccessful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I made it using `slot-scope` look:

```
<v-select
  v-model="twoWayComputed"
  :items="items"
  label="scoped"
>
  <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
    {{ selected }}
  </template>
  <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
    {{ data.item }}
  </template>
</v-select>
```

```
  data: () => ({
    selected: "Foo",
    allowChanges: false,
    items: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Fizz', 'Buzz']
  }),
  computed: {
    twoWayComputed: {
      get(){
        return this.selected
      },
      set(val) {
        if (this.allowChanges) {
          console.log("updating")
          this.selected = val
        } 
      }
    }
  }
```

[check-out-my-codepen](https://codepen.io/Adam_Orlov/pen/oRKLxB?editors=1011)

Comment: Very creative solution. Thank you very much. I went with the other answer because it was a little easier to implement in my project.